# What is the unit of text height in ggplot2 annotate?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My goal is to adjust the hight of annotation according to coordinate scale.
To do so, could I know the unit of `size` in annotate function?
(Below, I put `size = 10` and it seems the size 10 is about 0.0125 or so.)

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(1, 1)) +
  annotate(
    "text", x = 1, y = 1, label = "My label",
    size = 10,
    hjust = 0
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size is in mm I believe. You can specify size in points by dividing by the constant `.pt`, which converts points into mm. Note that font size in theme elements is specified in points and doesn't require division by `.pt`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(1, 1)) +
  annotate(
    "text", x = 1, y = 1, label = "My label",
    size = 15/.pt,
    hjust = 0
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(size = 15),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 15)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>